# Endless calls of Control.OnMouseMove after calling Refresh

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I was overriding the OnMouseMove method to write the current coordinates to my control. The problem is that I have to trigger the OnPaint method to refresh the values. If I use Refresh (or even Invalidate) in the OnMouseMove an endless cascade of MouseMove events is triggered. Even if I don't move the mouse the events are raised with X and Y values zero. Why is that? And is there a better way to handle my problem than checking whether X and Y are zero before calling Refresh?

Thanks for help,
Werner

I'm using .Net 3.5 on Windows XP and this topic is referring to System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: It's a bug in your code.  We can't see it, post a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Does your event handling cause another OnPaint invocation? Are you debugging where switching between VS.Net and your app is causing the repaint each time you hit the break point?